# Is there a way to return LatLng, Google Maps' format for points, from a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-maps, flex3

Is there a way to return LatLng, Google Maps' format for points, from a mySQL database? I'm using Flex 3 and MySQL with Google Maps.

Currently, I select latitudes and longitudes from my mySQL table and then iterate over them in Flex in order to make the LatLng for Google Maps.

```
public function latLngCreator():void {
        myLatLngArray = [];
        var i:uint;
        var arrayCollectionLength:int = myData.length;

        for  (i=0; i < arrayCollectionLength; i++) {
            myLatLng = new LatLng(myData[i].latitude, myData[i].longitude);
            myLatLngArray.push(myLatLng);
             }
```

Is there a way to skip the above step and select the latitudes and longitudes from the table and create the LatLng in PHP? This way I wouldn't have to iterate over the result and hopefully it would be faster.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Wouldn't you just be moving the iteration from Flex to PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way for this to happen.  I am assuming you are using google maps v3.  google.maps.LatLng does not accept deserialized JS objects, it only accepts 2 parameters as (lat, lng).

Furthermore, moving from the back-end to the front-end the data has to be serialized, and then deserialized.  These actions can be just as performance intensive.

What you don't want to do, is write javascript/actionscript from PHP to create these objects.  I have seen this happen, and the delivery was too large to handle the file and compiled twice.

Comment: CrazyEnigma,

Thank you for your post. That's exactly what I needed to know. 

Thank you!